# How to properly write query so I don't get unexpected token exception?

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
    public static List<BigDecimal> getTripsRevenueByCompany(Company company) {
        try (Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            return session.createQuery("SELECT price FROM Trip RIGHT JOIN TripDriverVehicle ON TripDriverVehicle.trip_id = Trip.id WHERE Trip.company_id = " + company.getId() + ",TripDriverVehicle.is_done = 1", BigDecimal.class).list();
        }
    }
```

This is the query I am trying to get.

I don't know how to write it properly tho. Tried a lot of different stuff.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 132 [SELECT price FROM entity.Trip RIGHT JOIN entity.TripDriverVehicle ON TripDriverVehicle.trip_id = Trip.id WHERE Trip.company_id = 51,TripDriverVehicle.is_done = 1]
```

What I am trying to do is to get the `price` of trips from the table `Trip`, but only for trips that are marked as `is_done=1` in the `TripDriverVehicle` table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma instead of `and`:

```
... WHERE Trip.company_id = " + company.getId() 
+ ",TripDriverVehicle.is_done = 1
```

Should be:

```
... WHERE Trip.company_id = " + company.getId()
+ " and TripDriverVehicle.is_done = 1
```